# command not found when executing nested bash scripts

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am having a bash script that is executing another bash script:

ex:

script name "rotator" is calling script name "s3-get" like below

```
!# /bin/bash
...
./s3-get {and params here}
```

All commands as "cat", "basename" etc. run correctly here

Within the "s3-get" script there is code as:

```
!# /bin/bash
cat > /dev/null << EndOfLicense
...
readonly weAreKnownAs="$(basename $0)"
...
main "$@"
```

So, if I simply execute the s3-get script directly from shell, it runs perfectly. When I try to execute it from "rotator" script, I get the error "cat: command not found". I can fix this by changing "cat" with "/bin/cat" just that I don't think this is correct since, as I stated above, the script runs correctly when executed as standalone. If I fix the "cat" command as above, the next error that raises is "basename: command not found", then "main: command not found"

I am pretty new to shell programming, so any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: It sounds like one of your shell scripts is modifying the `PATH` variable, which is how the shell finds commands when you don't give it a fully qualified command name like `/bin/cat`.

Comment: I would hope both scripts begin with "#!/bin/bash" not "!# /bin/bash" i.e. first hash then bang and no spaces.

Comment: You can always add "echo $PATH" at any point in the scripts to see what the PATH is set to. You can also type that command into your terminal and see what your path is normally set to outside of any scripts and then set it the same inside the scripts as the second line.

Comment: @mklement0 Maybe, but unusual, and anyway "!#" is definitely wrong.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Good point re the OP getting the shebang wrong (`!#` rather than the correct `#!`), but spaces after the `#!` are OK, although unusual - "rather, blanks after the shebang have traditionally been allowed" (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))

Comment: Sorry guys, I got the shebang wrong here (typo), but in the code it actually is #!. I also tried echo $PATH and in the "rotator" file I get 

/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games

but I was not able to see the results when I set it in the "s3-get" script. 

Also, I must point that all the scripts are in "/root/scripts/RotateVideos" directory

Comment: Add `-x` to both `#!` lines and see if the debugging output helps.

Comment: I did the following in the "rotator" script 

`-x #!/bin/bash`

and I got "-x: command not found"

Comment: Where's the `EndOfLicense` on a line by itself? If this is a _here document_, you need to terminate it.

Comment: I found the actual problem. Few lines above in the "rotator" file, before calling the "s3-get" script, I have var named FILE that actually was causing the problem. When I renamed that var to FILE_NAME, everything started working correctly.c Thank you guys and sorry for bothering.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/root/scripts/RotateVideos' >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc` in the command line and then just call it using `s3-get` in your script. Alternatively use `cd /root/scripts/RotateVideos && bash s3-get`.